# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound is not playing on iOS 6

Tags: ios

I am using the following code to play sound in my application

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource: @"sound" ofType:@"mp3"]], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

It is working fine in iOS 7 and above, but it's not playing on iPod which is running on iOS 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem within the simulator itself. If you start your application on your device, everything works just fine